# Hibernate have to wait for a few seconds before I can get the object that I just created

Tags: java, hibernate, session

With this session handler:

```
public class SessionHandler {
    private static SessionFactory DBContext;
    static {
        try {
            DBContext = HibnerateConfiguration.config().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(t);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Returns a session anyway. If currently no session exist, open a new one;
     * If there is a current session, use the existing one.
     */
    @Override
    public Session getSession() {
        try {
            return DBContext.getCurrentSession();
        }
        catch (HibernateException he) {
            logger.error("session already exist.");
            return DBContext.getCurrentSession();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        DBContext.close();
    }
}
```

and the following create and get methods:

```
public Serializable create(T type_entity) {
    Session session = getSessionHandler().getSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Serializable result = session.save(type_entity);
        tx.commit();
        return result;
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        getSessionHandler().close();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T get(Serializable id) throws InvalidRequestException {
    Session session = getSessionHandler().getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    try {
        Object obj = session.get(_classtype, id);
        if (obj == null) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException(String.format("requested object with id %s does not exist.", id));
        } else {
            return (T)obj;
        }
    } catch(HibernateException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        getSessionHandler().close(); 
    }
}
```

When I create an object that returns me id = 4, and if immediately I make a request on browser that eventually ask for the new object of id 4, I have to wait for a few seconds (last time I tried is > 3 seconds).

When the id is returned from the create, the data should already exist. However the get returns null. I highly suspect the get is using the old cache which then is updated every a few seconds, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Let me know if any info is required and I am happy to provide them.

Comment: Try commiting a transaction in get method.

Comment: @Whatzs tried, but still have the same problem.